# C best way to read input from this test file and test for EOF

Tags: c, io, eof

Hey everyone im very new to the C programming language and i am trying to read from a simple .txt file which contains this information:

```
  13 11 2011 13 10 00 GS452 45 20
  13 11 2011 15 14 23 EI597 60 30
  13 11 2011 15 34 35 EI600 20 15
```

currently i am using fscaf to read in the whole line then store them in correct variables in my structure. I looked up online and it seems that checking for EOF isnt as straight forward as it seems using fscanf as you it returns the amount of "items" read.

Using my below code and the above file:

1) which is the best way to read and store the information from the file in the correct place

2) the best way to check for EOF so it stops and the end of file/doesnt read empty files.

Header file:

```
  #ifndef MAYDAY_STRUCT_H
  #define   MAYDAY_STRUCT_H

  #ifdef    __cplusplus
   extern "C" {
   #endif

typedef struct {
    /* unsigned because these values cannot be negative*/

    unsigned int day;
    unsigned int month;
    unsigned int year;
    unsigned int hour;
    unsigned int mins;
    unsigned int secs;
    char ais[5];
    unsigned int l_boat_time;
    unsigned int heli_time;


} mayday_call;

void read_may_day_file();

#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
```

main.c

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include "mayday_struct.h"


 int main(int argc, char** argv) {


read_may_day_file();


return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
 }

void read_may_day_file() {

char locof[30];
char eofTest;
mayday_call mday;



printf("please enter the location of the input file \n");
scanf("%s", locof);

FILE *fp;
fp = fopen(locof, "r");


if (fp) {



        fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d %d %d %d %s %d %d", &mday.day, &mday.month, &mday.year, &mday.hour, &mday.mins, &mday.secs, mday.ais, &mday.l_boat_time, &mday.heli_time);


        printf("reading file mayday_1.txt \n"
                "day %d \n"
                "month %d \n"
                "yr %d \n"
                "hour % d\n"
                "mins %d \n"
                "sec %d \n"
                "ais %s \n"
                "lBoattime %d\n"
                "helitime %d \n", mday.day, mday.month,
                mday.year, mday.hour, mday.mins, mday.secs, mday.ais, mday.l_boat_time, mday.heli_time);

        fclose(fp);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I would suggest using `fgets` it will read from a file line by line, and return NULL when there is nothing left to read. If everything in your case is on the same line I would probably stick with `fscanf`, but you could also use `strtok` and read in the whole line and then parse through it using `strtok`

Take a look here for some more info: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm

If you were looking to use `fscanf` you were saying that it returns the amount that was read, so if nothing was read, then you have reached the end of the file.

Don't forget you also have to open the files that you wish to read and close them when you are done.

Comment: i looked at that but i wasnt sure how to then transfer the information from fgets as it stores it in an array into my variables. I am new to C as i said but wouldnt it read the number 11 as 1 1? (2 seperate 1 chars)

Comment: @chrisedwards not to my knowledge...it would read the whole line, then you if you use `strtok` and set the delimeter as a space (which is what I am assuming each number is separated by) you can then use `atoi` or `strtol` to convert that string to an int.

Comment: Also, if you were using `fscanf` which I think I would do, set up a `while` loop that says `while(fscanf(...) != EOF)` and that will keep reading until there is nothing left to read.

Comment: @mesales so in the scanf(...) i would put my normal scanf line so fscaf("%d %d %d .............", ......) and make sure its greater than 0? which is basically saying make sure the amount of read variables is greater than 0? im use to Java so C confuses me a bit at the moment :L

Comment: @chrisedwards yeah I had to do the same transition (from java to C) and it's a bit overwhelming at first, but it gets easier. I made a mistake, it was supposed to be `fscanf` and it would have to be >= 0, because it can return 0 while still reading in things, but for your case you could say `while(fscanf(..) == #ofStuffReadIn)`... You could also just straight up do `!=EOF`

Comment: @mesales i tried: while (fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d %d %d %d %s %d %d", &mday.day, &mday.month,
                &mday.year, &mday.hour, &mday.mins, &mday.secs, mday.ais,
                &mday.l_boat_time, &mday.heli_time) != EOF) { do stuff } but it keeps reading the first line from the file, then throws an error in my linux terminal saying double corruption free

Comment: @chrisedwards so how about trying `>= 0`?

Comment: So to neaten things up a bit also... you should always check to make sure the file opens properly. Which you kind of do, but this is how i've always done it: `if(fopen(locof, "r") == NULL) {printf("Could not open file %c\n", locof); exit(1);}` This will ensure that your program will not crash if the file is unable to be opened

Comment: managed to get it to work using EOF, not sure what i changed cheers mate, do you wanna make it a solution to get rep or something?

Comment: btw `char eoftest` is never used, so I would just get rid of it.

Comment: ye sorted that now, allthough i get a compile warning saying " that it expects a char * as an argument, but char (*) [5] is present" this refers to the argument mday.ais since ais is a char array

Comment: what is the exact warning? because if it is saying it expects `char *` as an argument i would assume that is because you are using `char ** argv` in your arguments, I know I use `char * argv[]` but its the same thing. Try it let me know what happens

Comment: ooohhhh I think I know what's going on! for your `scanf` you need to `scanf("%s", &locof)` That is probably what the error is for.

Comment: cheers, seems to have sorted it :) thanks for the help metsales.